# How send undefined object keys in Angular without hardcoding them

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of keys in an object, and I'm trying to check which of them is undefined when I send them. The problem is if I send an undefined key, it will get removed. Right now, I'm hardcoding them into the scope variable.

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="createRecipe(recipe.alias, recipe.selectedCategory, recipe.description, recipe.instructions)">
            <label>Beer Name</label></br>
            <input ng-model="recipe.alias"></br>
            <label>Category</label></br>
            <select ng-options="beer.alias as beer.alias for beer in beerTypes" ng-model="recipe.selectedCategory" ng-change="filterByCategory(selectedCategory)">
            </select></br>
            <label>Description</label></br>
            <textarea ng-model="recipe.description" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-box"></textarea></br>
            <label>Recipe</label></br>
            <textarea ng-model="recipe.instructions" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-box"></textarea></br>
            <input type="submit" class="button-color btn btn-default"></br>
        </form>
```

Angular Function:

```
$scope.createRecipe = function(alias, selectedCategory, description, instructions){
        $scope.recipe.alias = alias;
        $scope.recipe.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
        $scope.recipe.description = description;
        $scope.recipe.instructions = instructions;
//Then I send it to the server
}
```

This works, but it's ugly, and it still doesn't show up on the backend.

Comment: I'm using underscorejs's [defaults](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) for setting default values to objects. It's not an answer because it's off-topic - but still handy

Comment: Try `$scope.recipe.alias = alias || "";`

Comment: Also try using `ng-value=""` to initialize them

Comment: `null` survives `JSON.stringify()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the keys to be defined even if the value is undefined, you could define the scope variables in your controller and set the to `""`. Then backend you can check if empty, eg in php use `if (empty([your var]))`

To simplify things, When you submit the data is on your scope so the function can just send the $scope.recipe data.

```
$scope.recipe = {alias: '', selectedCategory: '', description: '', instructions: ''};
$scope.createRecipe = function(){
    //send it to the server
    $http.post('url', $scope.recipe).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
};

<form ng-submit="createRecipe()">
    <label>Beer Name</label></br>
    <input ng-model="recipe.alias"></br>
    <label>Category</label></br>
    <select ng-options="beer.alias as beer.alias for beer in beerTypes" ng-model="recipe.selectedCategory" ng-change="filterByCategory(selectedCategory)">
    </select></br>
    <label>Description</label></br>
    <textarea ng-model="recipe.description" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-box"></textarea></br>
    <label>Recipe</label></br>
    <textarea ng-model="recipe.instructions" cols="50" rows="5" class="input-box"></textarea></br>
    <input type="submit" class="button-color btn btn-default"></br>
</form>
```

Comment: I did this, but on the back end it is still not showing the undefined variables. EDIT: dandavis was correct: the backend doesn't transfer undefined. I set them to null originally and things work now. Minus that though, this code works. Thank you!